# SQL Developer Oracle TNS Protocol Adapter Error

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, listener, tns

I am having trouble getting SQL developer running as system.

```
     C:\Users\me>lsnrctl start

     LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 21-JAN-2021 18:54:20

      Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

      Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

      TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
      TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error
```

I tried to start it cause the status show it not running

```
       C:\Users\me>lsnrctl status

       LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 21-JAN-2021 19:06:29

        Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

       Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=computerName)(PORT=1521)))
       TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
       TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
       TNS-00511: No listener
        64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
       Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC) 
 (KEY=EXTPROC1522)))
      TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
       TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
      TNS-00511: No listener
      64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

My tnsnames.ora and listener.ora are in C:\dbhomeXE\network\admin

listener.ora is

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
   (SID_LIST =
     (SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle\dbhomeXE)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
  (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Oracle\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
)
  )

 LISTENER =
   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
     (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = computername)(PORT = 1521))
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522))
)
 )
```

Then my tnsnames.ora is

```
  XE =
   (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = computername)(PORT = 1521))
         (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
)
     )

  LISTENER_XE =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = computername)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522))
     )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
      ) 
 )
```

I am also running the command prompt as admin. Can anyone help me understand what is happening?

Comment: are you running a local firewall, or anti-virus software?

Comment: No I am not myself. it has worked in the past also and nothing has changed since then

Comment: what version of Windows are you using? I see Oracle 18c in the listener header...

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236967/oracle-listener-not-running-and-wont-start/42433149

Comment: Also, make sure Windows Firewall and any anti-virus software like McAfee or Norton are disabled.

Comment: thanks Ill look through this. My log folder is empty so I might need to troubleshoot that too